# Error: Empty cluster created at iteration 1. When emptyaction does not support

Tags: matlab, loops, error-handling, k-means

For several days I am trying hard to handle the problem which occurs while I run k-means algorithm on my matrix. I have 12 clusters and the dimension of matrix after applying PCA is 144x10. I would like to make 20 iterations and create confusion matrices on them. Here is my code:

```
ReduceFV=score(:,1:10);

Activities=[ones(1,12), 2*ones(1,12), 3*ones(1,12), 4*ones(1,12),...
5*ones(1,12), 6*ones(1,12), 7*ones(1,12), 8*ones(1,12),...
9*ones(1,12), 10*ones(1,12), 11*ones(1,12), 12*ones(1,12)]';

A=zeros(20,12,12);
mean_error=zeros(1,20);
std_error=zeros(1,20);
R=zeros(20,12,12);
J=zeros(20,12,12);
for i=(1:20);
       [clusterIndex, centroids] = kmeans(ReduceFV,12,'emptyaction', 'drop');
       A(i,:,:)=confusionmat(Activities, clusterIndex);
       R=reshape(A(i,:,:),12,12);
       mean_error(i)=1-trace(R)/sum(R(:)); % mean of errors
       std_error(i)=std(mean_error);
       [J(i,:,:),numcorrect,precision,recall,F] = getcm (Activities,clusterIndex);
end

figure
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==1,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==1,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
hold all
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==2,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==2,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==3,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==3,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==4,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==4,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==5,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==5,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==6,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==6,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==7,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==7,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==8,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==8,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==9,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==9,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==10,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==10,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==11,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==11,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)
plot(DataAll(clusterIndex==12,1),DataAll(clusterIndex==12,2),'.','MarkerSize',12)

plot(centroids(:,1),centroids(:,2),'kx','MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
legend('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7','A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11', 'A12', 'centers');
hold off
```

The problem is that, when I run the loop, I get error message, saying "Empty cluster created at iteration 1." 
What to do when emptyaction does not help, is there any other solution? 
As well in the plot clusterIndex and Centroids do not match each other. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Please Help! I would really appreciate any suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: This code works perfectly in my system: `ReduceFV=ones(144,10);for i=1:20
       [clusterIndex, centroids] = kmeans(ReduceFV,12,'emptyaction', 'drop');
end`

Your code should also work. In fact, my `reducedFV` matrix has only one cluster.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I think the problem is that I have many clusters and matrix is somehow 'problematic'. It means, after some iteration it looses all the values and gives me error. Can be this problem really caused by the matrix itself? and what is solution then if it is? Thank you!

Comment: upload the .mat file of your matrix and all other variables. So that I can run the code and check myself.

Comment: It would be big pleasure, thanks! Here is the link for variable ReduceFV.mat: http://tempsend.com/FCB42B4ED9

Comment: Even when I try to plot the data, cluster indexes and centroids do not match.